# Office 365 SharePoint SSO with ADFS

Tags: office-365, adfs, sso

We have an Office 365 SharePoint site setup: mycompany.sharepoint.com  ... if users click on that URL, they are presented with the Office 365 login page.  We've implemented ADFS and setup Smartlinks so that users can browse to sharepoint.mycompany.com, which bounces the user through the auth process and lands them on mycompany.sharepoint.com all logged in.

This is great and working perfectly well.

My question is this:  When users find some interesting content in the Office 365 SharePoint site, they typically will email a link for that content to their buddies.  However, that link comes across as mycompany.sharepoint.com/pages/somepage.aspx ..this is no good because if the receiving user is not already auth'ed by way of the SmartLink, they're presented with the Office 365 login page again.

Is there any way around this?